# Disable TimeOffset modifiers in Draw Mode

Tags: modifiers, grease-pencil, draw-mode

I've made a walk cycle with grease pencil and looped it with a TimeOffset modifier.
After the walk cycle is looped a couple of times, I animated the character jumping within the same grease pencil object, and then used a second TimeOffset modifier to display this animation. I used keyframes to display and hide the TimeOffset modifiers, so I can switch between the walk cycle and the jump animation.

Now I want to add a third animation to the grease pencil object, but when I go into draw mode I cannot easily disable the TimeOffset modifiers.

When I go to edit mode the modifiers are not visible, but this mode doesn't allow me to draw with grease pencil.

I have tried to enable the Modifier Tools add-on, but it doesn't show up in my interface.

I would like to know how to temporarily disable all modifiers in Draw Mode. Thanks in advance for any help!